# AWS Serverless Protect API Paths for different User Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

right now my head is exploding from all the information about AWS. :) So I need your help.

I have the following architecture on AWS: API Gateway, Lambda, Cognito. I am using the serverless framework to configure everything.
On Lambda several functions are deployed. Let's say the API and functions are like:

```
GET /user
GET /vehicle
POST /vehicle
```

I have two types of users A and B. A is an admin and should access everything, but B is restricted to certain paths, e.g.

```
GET /user >>> only A
GET /vehicle >>> B
POST /vehicle >>> only A
```

How can I achieve this with Cognito, API Gateway and Lambda.

The information/ideas I've found so far are:

- one can use different IAM roles (e.g. "normal user" and "admin")

  - here I don't know where and how to assign the users (stored in Cognito) to certain roles ([source1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html), [source2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html))
- one can use a custom authorizer ([source](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/))

  - here I can only find examples that are working with Auth0.. but I want to use Cognito
- use Pre-Token trigger on Cognito pool to update the claims in the token ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html))

Which is the best way to go? Or is there a better solution? 
Nevertheless a good example would be nice. So far I've found only examples with like 50 lines of code, which do not suit my case. So actually my problem might be that I don't know how and where to start..

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit bias because I've used custom authorizers in the past.
But they are probably the most flexible solution, from those you mentioned.

I've actually used the custom authorizer with cognito user pools before there was a cognito authorizer.

At the time this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/ helped me a lot to get started.

Later i found that i should take advantage of the caching of the policies sent by the authorizer once I was doing a lot of validation and since user permissions didn't change that often. For that i had to send as a response a policy that would cover all the endpoints that were allowed to be invoked by the authenticated user.

EDIT:
On the custom authorizer you are able to [check the user information by calling cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminListGroupsForUser.html).  After that you can give the policies for the user if it is a default user

```
{   "principalId": "yyyyyyyy", // The principal user identification associated with the token sent by the client.   "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow|Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{regionId}:{accountId}:{appId}/{stage}/GET/user"
      }
    ]   } }
```

And for admins you just send another Policies

```
{
  "principalId": "yyyyyyyy", // The principal user identification associated with the token sent by the client.
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow|Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{regionId}:{accountId}:{appId}/{stage}/GET/user"
      },
   {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow|Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{regionId}:{accountId}:{appId}/{stage}/*/vehicle"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I had a look and your link helped me a lot!  I've used the custom authorizer but later I've decided to go with the Cognito Authorizer.
Nevertheless the polices applied to the user doesn't seem to work..
I have three groups with different kind of policies. E.g. policy `default` can only invoke lambda function with arn `a`. A user with that policy (attached to a role) can still invoke every function. Any idea?

Comment: On the custom authorizer you are able to check the user information, with that you can check which group he belongs and build your response withthe corresponding policies.

Comment: Edited the answer with more information, that might help

Comment: But how do I do that if I stick with the `Cognito Authorizer`?

Comment: to be honest i'm not sure if you are able to do that, but i might be wrong

Comment: Ok but thanks for your help. This has moved me into the right direction! :)

Comment: glad that helped :)

Comment: Hey small update on my problem. The cognito authorizer seems to be like a yes/no authorizer. Therefore I went with the AWS IAM authorizer and Cognito User Groups. For more see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540390/aws-restrict-cognito-authorized-user-to-specific-lambda-functions
The option you provided with the custom authorizer is an alternative.